# Paho MQTT host invalid argument when using an IP address as hostname?

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

REVISION: Please note I am now using IP address 10.0.0.15, my device publishing to the MQTT broker is 10.0.0.122. This is still all working through terminal.

I think I am getting somewhere with an MQTT connector. I have moved forward after having issues as describe in the post below

[Can't connect to localhost Mosquitto Broker with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994506/cant-connect-to-localhost-mosquitto-broker-with-javascript/55995838?noredirect=1#comment98641006_55995838)

I am now seeing the following error.

```
         mqttws31.js:1585 Uncaught Error: AMQJS0013E Invalid argument 
         169.254.118.199 for host.
         at new M (mqttws31.js:1585)
         at startConnect (n.js:29)
         at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):107)
```

which according to the js file indicates a match error. I have tried prefixing the ip address to be wss://169.254.118.199 but this doesn't resolve the issue. Do you know what could be causing this?

I have tried the following

```
 wss://169.254.118.199
 ws://169.254.118.199
 wss://localhost
 tcp://169.254.118.199
 tcp://localhost
```

They all produce the same error

This is the bit of code in mqttws31.js that the error points to.

```
          if (arguments.length == 2) {
          // host: must be full ws:// uri
          // port: clientId
          clientId = port;
          uri = host;
          var match = uri.match(/^(wss?):\/\/((\[(.+)\])|([^\/]+?))(:(\d+))? 
          (\/.*)$/);
          if (match) {
          host = match[4]||match[2];
          port = parseInt(match[7]);
          path = match[8];
          } else {
          --> this is where error is pointing throw new Error(format(ERROR.INVALID_ARGUMENT,[host,"host"]));
          }
          } else {
          if (arguments.length == 3) {
            clientId = path;
            path = "/mqtt";
          }
          if (typeof port !== "number" || port < 0)
            throw new Error(format(ERROR.INVALID_TYPE, [typeof port, "port"]));
          if (typeof path !== "string")
            throw new Error(format(ERROR.INVALID_TYPE, [typeof path, "path"]));

          var ipv6AddSBracket = (host.indexOf(":") != -1 && host.slice(0,1) != "[" && 
          host.slice(-1) != "]");
          uri = "ws://"+(ipv6AddSBracket?"["+host+"]":host)+":"+port+path;
          }
```

EDIT: in the print out I am seeing the following being sent to the Paho client on my webpage:

```
    Connecting to: 10.0.0.122 on port: 8083
    Using the following client value: clientID-64
```

I am hoping to sucessfully connect with the IP address and get the MQTT payload

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the eth0, when I run Mosquitto throughthe terminal I can connect, when I run in this code it will connect to my device. The device IP is actually 169.254.84.122, which really doesn't make any sense. Also when I try to set a static ip on eth0 the pi just wont take it. im stumped at the minute.

Comment: Edit the code to print to the console exactly what you are feeding into the `Paho.MQTT.Client(host, Number(port), clientID);` and add this to the question so we can see EXACTLY what you are passing to the code.

Comment: @hardlib I have added an *EDIT near the bottom of the original question showing what is being sent to Paho.MQTT.Client(host,Number(port), clientID);

Comment: I have tested again, I am now getting past this host name error and I now keep having a connection time out? mqttws31.js:977 WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.0.0.15:8083/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 2):

To get the error you are seeing, you can not be using the code you have posted in the other questions:

```
clientID = "clientID-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100);

// Fetch the hostname/IP address and port number from the form
host = document.getElementById("host").value;
port = document.getElementById("port").value;
// Print output for the user in the messages div

// Initialize new Paho client connection
 client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, Number(port), clientID);
```

That error can only happen if you only pass 2 arguments to the `Paho.MQTT.Client()` constructor not 3. In which case the first argument is interpreted as a full URI (e.g. `ws://10.0.0.122:8083/mqtt`), the second as the ClientID.

Comment: Hey, so after some battling I've worked out where I was going wrong, essentially, I am connecting to the pi over WiFi and using my pi wlan0 192.168.1.200, but I was trying to access the MQTT through the eth0 and the web browser didn't like it. So I am now hardwired and doing everything over eth0, I can connect, but when I go to subscribe to the topic, it just hangs there. I have also tried with this online MQTT tester,http://www.lazyengineers.com/mqtt-websocket/, it does the same thing, it will connect to the broker but just hangs there when subscribing to the topic. Any ideas what it may be?